# Which API is used to get email contacts from google?

Tags: node.js, api, google-api-nodejs-client

I have looked around for some time to try and get email contacts of authenticated users but could only come across the [contacts api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts) which responds with phone contacts and circle api which is only for [google plus domains.](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/people/list)

Answer (score 0):

Just little googling...
Have you tried [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-contacts) ?

Comment: This returns the phone contacts synced with Google. I've tried this !